# Objective-C: .a fat file with more than armv6/7

Tags: objective-c, xcode, static-libraries, armv6

Although I set up my static library project in XCode to build armv6, armv7, i386 and x86_64, it does not build a full fat file :-(

`lipo -info lib...a` tells me that it is a fat file with armv6 and armv7, nothing else, no more architectures inside.

How to get them all put into one file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have the "Valid architectures" (`VALID_ARCHS`) build setting set to narrow the set of architectures for which your target is built.

Comment: there's also a "build for current architecture only" flag too you might want to check

Comment: "build for active architecture only"=no, "valid architectures"="armv7 armv6 i386 x86_64"; something wrong there?

Comment: Not that I can tell. What does the build log itself say that clang or GCC builds for?

Comment: it's saying `CreateUniversalBinary DerivedData/TestSDKLib/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libTestSDKLib.a normal "armv7 armv6 i386 x86_64"` but `lipo -info` tells me about armv6 and armv7 only.

Comment: Does other build steps show that it compiles for i386 and x86_64 too?

Comment: no, only when i build for iphone/ipad simulator instead of device. how to build for both in the same step?